# Closure of a subfunctor (of a sheaf)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Sorry if this is standard, but I couldn't find a reference.

*Background:*

- Let $F: \textbf{Aff}^\text{op} \to \textbf{Set}$ be a functor. If $R$ is a ring (commutative with $1$) and $I \subseteq R$ is an ideal, one has the subfunctor of $\text{Spec}(R)$ given by

$$S \mapsto \{ \varphi \in Hom(R , S) : \varphi(I) = 0 \}.$$

A subfunctor $G$ of $F$ is **closed** if for every ring $R$ and every morphism $\text{Spec}(R) \to F$ the inverse image of $G$ is a subfunctor of the form above.

- The **intersection** of a family of subfunctors of $F$ is defined in the naive way.

*Actual Question:*
What's the definition of the **closure** of a subfunctor? Does the naive construction (intersection of all closed subfunctors which contain $G$) work?

If it simplifies matters, I'm particularly interested in the case when $F$ is a sheaf in the fpqc topology on $\textbf{Aff}$ (but NOT necessarily representable by a scheme).

In addition to answers, any references would be much appreciated! :) Thanks so much!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE :-) Your idea should work – what makes you doubt it does? Have you tried checking that the intersection is closed?

Comment: @Ben Thanks! Yes the intersection of a family of closed subfunctors is again closed. I worry because the union of subfunctors is not so straightforward:  A family $\{G_\alpha \}$ of subfunctors of $F$ **covers** $F$ if $F(k) = \bigcup_{\alpha} G_\alpha(k)$ for all _fields_ $k$. Perhaps I should have asked the following question instead: If I'm thinking of a sheaf $F$ (let's say on the Zariski site) as a generalization of a scheme, is there a notion of a "topology" on $F$ (analogous to the Zariski topology on a scheme) with respect to which I can take closures of subfunctors?

Comment: 1. Since your question is unanswered so far, you can easily edit it if you want to include that into the question. 2. One though towards the new question: By a result of Kuratowski, a closure-operation is the closure operation of a topological space if and only if it satisfies the four https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms — I think the only non-trivial part for your closure would be to preserve finite unions..?

Comment: @Ben Thanks again! After doing a bit more searching it looks like the answer is to the original question is "yes, the naive construction works", and the answer to the second question is "topoi" (an intimidating area of mathematics!). I'll post this as an answer soon! Regarding your second remark: that is a cool theorem! Unfortunately if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are closed subfunctors of $F$, it is not in general true that the subfunctor $A \mapsto G_1(A) \cup G_2(A)$ is closed, even in the case when $F = \text{Spec}(R)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "yes"! The closure of a subfunctor is defined to be the intersection of all closed subfunctors containing it. See, for example, Demazure and Gabriel's excellent book: "Introduction to Algebraic Geometry and Algebraic Groups".